# Image navbar hover

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar which displays a list of image links. I want to change the image based on hover and selection. This is my result:

[image]

html:

```
<li>
    <a href='' id='home' />
</li>
```

css:

```
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
}

nav li a #home {
    background-image: url('../images/home.png');
}

nav li a:hover #home {
    background-image: url('../images/home-hover.png');
}

nav li a:selected #home {
    background-image: url('../images/home-selected.png');
}
```

Why isn't this working correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Your css is looking for a child with id #home. It should be `nav li a#home:hover{}` etc.

You'll also need to set either block or inline-block as well as width/height on the a tag.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6HmLP/1/

Comment: I still get the same result and by the way the width, height and inline-block are inherited from li.

Comment: Just to clarify: the `width` `height` and `display` of `a` are __not__ inherited from `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to address it like this:

```
nav li a#home { ... }
nav li a#home:hover { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `a` tag and include content: `<a href='' id='home' />some text</a>`

You should also display your `a` as a block or inline-block and give it a width and height so your background image can actually display as intended.

Also, your selectors are wrong. By saying `a #home`, you're looking for "*any element with an id of `home`, which is a descendent element of `a`*". Which doesn't exist in your HTML. Instead, you can target it with `a#home` which means "*the `a` element that has an id of `home`*".

Comment: The a tag is already closed. Please don't try to teach a language before you learn it.

Comment: You're kidding, right? Please explain how that is valid HTML?

Comment: In any case, `a` is a non-void element in HTML.

Comment: Please can you modify your opening `a` tag to not be self-closing